# php in Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, mac, php5, apache-2.2

I have uncommented the following line to have php beeing taken into account by apache:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

I then created a test.php file with

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and restarted apache

```
sudo apachectl graceful
```

But the php file is not taken into account, I just get the plain html.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

see this http://www.phpied.com/installing-php-and-apache-on-mac-osx-that-was-pretty-easy/

Comment: I followed this one also but did not get any more chance. I went with MAMB instead.

Answer (score 1):

From the Terminal:

```
sudo cp /private/etc/php.ini.default /private/etc/php.ini
```

And then restart Apache again. You need a php.ini file to use PHP, and by default there is not one in place.